MAX6675 SPI communication with PIC microcontroller
I'm using a PIC16F1832X to communicate with a MAX6675 thermocouple-to-digital converter. As I read the values of the temperature and the SSPBUF register, they are way too high; SSPBUF is 223.
I assume that something is wrong with the SPI communication or the bitshifting of the 12-bit values of the MAX6675. I'm also using a PICKIT3 to debug and readout sensor values.
My code is attached:
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// CONFIG1
#pragma config FEXTOSC = OFF    // FEXTOSC External Oscillator mode Selection bits (Oscillator not enabled)
#pragma config RSTOSC = EXT1X   // Power-up default value for COSC bits (EXTOSC operating per FEXTOSC bits)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable bit (CLKOUT function is disabled; I/O or oscillator function on OSC2)
#pragma config CSWEN = ON       // Clock Switch Enable bit (Writing to NOSC and NDIV is allowed)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // Master Clear Enable bit (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR; Weak pull-up enabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bits (WDT disabled; SWDTEN is ignored)
#pragma config LPBOREN = OFF    // Low-power BOR enable bit (ULPBOR disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset enabled, SBOREN bit ignored)
#pragma config BORV = LOW       // Brown-out Reset Voltage selection bit (Brown-out voltage (Vbor) set to 2.45V)
#pragma config PPS1WAY = ON     // PPSLOCK bit One-Way Set Enable bit (The PPSLOCK bit can be cleared and set only once; PPS registers remain locked after one clear/set cycle)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config DEBUG = OFF      // Debugger enable bit (Background debugger disabled)

// CONFIG3
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // User NVM self-write protection bits (Write protection off)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low Voltage Programming Enable bit (Low Voltage programming enabled. MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR. MCLRE configuration bit is ignored.)

// CONFIG4
#pragma config CP = OFF         // User NVM Program Memory Code Protection bit (User NVM code protection disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data NVM Memory Code Protection bit (Data NVM code protection disabled)

// Configure the pins
#define CS LATC3
#define SO PORTC1
#define SCK LATC0
#define _XTAL_FREQ 2000000    // Example: 2 MHz

// Function to initialize the SPI
void spi_init(void) {
    // Set the SPI pins as outputs
    TRISC3 = 0; // CS
    TRISC1 = 1; // SO
    TRISC0 = 0; // SCK
    ANSELC = 0x00;
    SSP1STATbits.SMP = 1;  // input Data is sampled at the end
    SSP1STATbits.CKE = 0;  // Transmission occurs from Idle to Active
    // Master mode Fosc/4
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPM0 = 0;
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPM1 = 0;
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPM2 = 0;
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPM3 = 0;
    SSP1CON1bits.CKP = 1; // clock polarity is high
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPEN = 1; // Serial communication is Enabled
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPOV = 0; // Overflow is off
    SSP1CON1bits.WCOL = 0; // Write collision is off
    // Configure the SPI settings
    // SSPSTAT = 0xC0; // SMP=1 (Capture data at end of output time), CKE=1 (Transition from active to inactive)
    // SSPCON1 = 0x20; // SSPEN=1 (Enables serial port and configures SCK, SDO, SDI, and SS pins as serial port pins), CKP=0 (Idle state for clock is low), SSPM[3:0]=0010 (Master mode, clock = FOSC/64)
    // Deactivate the Slave Select (CS high)
    CS = 1;
}

// Function for SPI data transfer
uint8_t spi_transfer(uint8_t data) {
    // Load the byte to be sent into the buffer
    SSPBUF = data;
    // Wait for the transfer to complete
    while (!SSPSTATbits.BF);
    // Return the received byte
    return SSPBUF;
}

// Function to read temperature from MAX6675
uint16_t max6675_read_temp(void) {
    uint16_t temperature = 0;
    // Set CS low to start communication
    CS = 0;
    // Wait at least 220ms for temperature conversion
    __delay_ms(220);
    // Read the first 8 bits
    temperature = spi_transfer(0) << 8;
    // Read the next 8 bits
    temperature |= spi_transfer(0);
    // Set CS high to end communication
    CS = 1;
    // Shift the data right to accommodate MAX6675 format
    temperature >>= 3;
    return temperature;
}

void main(void) {
    // Initialize the SPI
    spi_init();
    // Variable to store the temperature
    uint16_t temperature;
    while (1) {
        // Read the temperature from MAX6675
        temperature = max6675_read_temp();
        // Print the temperature
        printf("Temperature: %d\n", temperature);
        // Wait for one second
        __delay_ms(1000);
    }
}


The default setting for TRISC1 is SPI input but the pins (input and outputs) can be changed with PPS (datasheet table 2 bottom footnotes 1,2). Have you changed the pins with PPS?

No i havent changed the pins in PPS. So you would change the xxxPPS to the Slave out pin? Its on 13.8 register

Are you sure you want CPOL =  1?

Do you mean SSP1CON1bits.CKP = 1; // clock polarity is high ? According to the datasheet it should be low

So where is SPI output (or MOSI)? TRISC1 is SPI input (or MISO).  MOSI = Master Out Slave In, MISO = Master In Slave Out.

I dont have a SPI outpout yet., because the max6675 only sends data and doesnt receive any

If possible, test the  MAX6675  separately. Maybe with an Arduino board.

The max6675 works absolutely fine with arduino. there you can use a special library.

From the data sheet:

This implies that an LSB has a weight of 0.25 Celsius.  You need to divide your result by four to provide a direct temperature output.

Yeah ur right, but the values i read are so much bigger than this 1/4. How would you config the SSP1CON and the SSPSTAT?

You have: SSP1CON1bits.CKP = 1; // clock polarity is high
The PIC16F18326 datsheet says:
SSP1CON1 Register:
CKP: Clock Polarity Select bit
In SPI mode:
1 = Idle state for clock is a high level
0 = Idle state for clock is a low level

The MAX6675 datsheet shows the idle polarity of the clock to be low:


Ur absolutely right. Changed CKP to 0. But still get wrong temp. readings. The value is about 59000

Are you sure you got the correct endianness?

Im not sure thats why i am asking for help. So what would you change ?

I didn't read the whole datasheet so make sure this is ok before doing it ... connect the thermocouple terminal (both T+ and T-) to ground. Do you get a value close to zero? if not what are the two 8 bit values that you read?

I just disconnected all Pins of the MAX6675. Its still showing the same value. There must be something wrong with the SPI communication.

Do you have a scope to connect to the SPI bus and see what's going on?

Yea, the Data (SDI) line doesnt react to a temperature rise. The SCK and CS look good on the scope.

If i read the temperature values they switch between 59000 and 50000. The SSP1BUF register shows a value of 23, or 255 which is correct i guess?
I added SSP1SPPS, SSP1CLKPPS, SSP1DATPPS and also RC0PPS and RC1PPS. Is there something else missing?
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
// CONFIG1
#pragma config FEXTOSC = OFF    // FEXTOSC External Oscillator mode Selection bits (Oscillator not enabled)
#pragma config RSTOSC = EXT1X   // Power-up default value for COSC bits (EXTOSC operating per FEXTOSC bits)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable bit (CLKOUT function is disabled; I/O or oscillator function on OSC2)
#pragma config CSWEN = ON       // Clock Switch Enable bit (Writing to NOSC and NDIV is allowed)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // Master Clear Enable bit (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR; Weak pull-up enabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bits (WDT disabled; SWDTEN is ignored)
#pragma config LPBOREN = OFF    // Low-power BOR enable bit (ULPBOR disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset enabled, SBOREN bit ignored)
#pragma config BORV = LOW       // Brown-out Reset Voltage selection bit (Brown-out voltage (Vbor) set to 2.45V)
#pragma config PPS1WAY = ON     // PPSLOCK bit One-Way Set Enable bit (The PPSLOCK bit can be cleared and set only once; PPS registers remain locked after one clear/set cycle)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config DEBUG = OFF      // Debugger enable bit (Background debugger disabled)

// CONFIG3
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // User NVM self-write protection bits (Write protection off)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low Voltage Programming Enable bit (Low Voltage programming enabled. MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR. MCLRE configuration bit is ignored.)

// CONFIG4
#pragma config CP = OFF         // User NVM Program Memory Code Protection bit (User NVM code protection disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data NVM Memory Code Protection bit (Data NVM code protection disabled)


// Configure the pins
#define CS LATC3
#define SO PORTC1
#define SCK LATC0
#define _XTAL_FREQ 400000    // Example: 64 MHz
// Function to initialize SPI
void spi_init(void) {
    // Set the SPI pins as outputs
        // Configure PPS for SPI
SSP1SSPPS = 0x13; // Assign RC3 as Slave Select (SS)
SSP1CLKPPS = 0x10; // Assign RC0 as Serial Clock (SCK)
SSP1DATPPS = 0x11; // Assign RC1 as Serial Data Input (SDI)
   // Set RxyPPS Registers for SPI Pins
RC0PPS = 0x14; // Set RC0 as SCK Output
RC1PPS = 0x15; // Set RC1 as SDI Input
//RC3PPS = 0x16; // Set RC3 as SS Output


TRISC3 = 0; // CS
TRISC1 = 1; // SO
TRISC0 = 0; // SCK
ANSELC = 0x00;
SSP1STATbits.SMP = 1;  // Input Data is sampled at end
SSP1STATbits.CKE = 1;  // Transmission occurs from Idle to Active
// Master mode Fosc/4
SSP1CON1bits.SSPM0 = 0;
SSP1CON1bits.SSPM1 = 0;
SSP1CON1bits.SSPM2 = 0;
SSP1CON1bits.SSPM3 = 0;
//
SSP1CON1bits.CKP = 0; // Clock polarity is low
SSP1CON1bits.SSPEN = 1; // Serial communication is Enabled
SSP1CON1bits.SSPOV = 1; // Overflow is off
SSP1CON1bits.WCOL = 0; // Write collision is off
    
    
    
     

    // Disable Slave Select (CS high)
    CS = 1;
}

uint8_t spi_transfer(uint8_t data) {
    // Load the byte to be sent into the buffer
    SSPBUF = data;

    // Wait until the transfer is complete
    while (!SSPSTATbits.BF);

    // Return the received byte
    return SSPBUF;
}

// Function to read temperature from MAX6675
uint16_t max6675_read_temp(void) {
    uint16_t temperature = 0;

    // Set CS low to initiate communication
    CS = 0;

    // Wait at least 220ms for temperature conversion
    __delay_ms(220);

    // Read the first 8 bits
    temperature = spi_transfer(0) << 8;

    // Read the next 8 bits
    temperature |= spi_transfer(0);

    // Set CS high to end communication
    CS = 1;

    // Shift the data right to accommodate MAX6675 format
    temperature >> 3;

    return temperature;
}

void main(void) {
    // Initialize SPI
    spi_init();

    // Variable to store temperature
    uint16_t temperature;

    while (1) {
        // Read temperature from MAX6675
        temperature = max6675_read_temp();

        // Print the temperature
        printf("Temperature: %d\n", temperature);

        // Wait for one second
        __delay_ms(1000);
    }
}


